# How to define order (setPriority) of Spannable in Android

Tags: android, spannable

I have few overlapping spans within SpannableStringBuilder. I would like to define order in which they will be implemented to Text.
Spannable have int flags

```
int SPAN_PRIORITY = 16711680;
int SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT = 16;
```

How can I use them? How many levels Spannable priority have? 
What is the default one?

Comment: If I implement Spannable with flag SPAN_PRIORITY it seems to get lower priority, than default, since it's a bitwise mask with zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define `priority` you have to utilize bits magic:

```
int priority = 123; // Should be in range [0..255].
int spanFlags = 0;
// ...
// Cleaning up priority bits.
spanFlags &= ~Spannable.SPAN_PRIORITY; 
// Injecting priority bits.
spanFlags |= (priority << Spannable.SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT) & Spannable.SPAN_PRIORITY;
// ...
sb.setSpan(what, start, end, spanFlags);
```

Comment: Thanks.
Does it make sense to do bitwise AND with zeros?
When I need to add other flags, should it be bitwise OR with setted priority, not AND?
Any ideas of what is default priority?

Comment: Bitwise AND with zeros produces zeros, where do we do this? If you don't want to dive into bit operations stuff, simply setup other flags before applying priority related bits. The default is 0, it's implied from other keys values.

Comment: `SPAN_PRIORITY` is a bit mask where priority responsible bits are `1`.
`SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT` is a number of the first bit in that mask from right side.
So, it means that we have to clear them first via `spanFlags &= ~Spannable.SPAN_PRIORITY; ` and then we have to setup them with new value with `spanFlags |= (priority << Spannable.SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT) & Spannable.SPAN_PRIORITY;`.

Comment: if spanFlags initially is 0, why do we need to clear it? Can other span flags affect this priority flags?
If i will need priority and other flag, sould I do bitwise OR to get bits from both flags?

Comment: We don’t need to if we start from ‘0’, but we cannot be sure when we are modifying the ‘flags’ value comes from outside.